# Winrt certificates

Tags: windows-runtime, certificate, pfx

I took over developing of winrt mobile app. I have one question, app has two certificates. "appName_StoreKey.pfx" and "appName_TemporaryKey.pfx". I cen easly create "appName_TemporaryKey.pfx" from visual studio. Where can I create "appName_StoreKey.pfx"? It is created during creating app packages to the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's created when you associate the project to a store app entity.

[image: associate menu item]